# Как сделать запрос не занятых ячеек?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы которые связаны по id, как выбрать те записи которые еще не связаны с таблицей.
Мне нужно получить третью запись потому что две остальные уже заняты. Как это сделать запросом ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table2
                   WHERE table1.id = table2.table1_id )
```